# Prove that the set of all grammatical sentences is denumerable

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that the set of all grammatical sentences of English is denumerable(Hint: Every grammatical sentence of English is a finite sequence of English words. First show that the set of all grammatical sentences is countable and then show that it is infinite.)

We construct a function $f: \mathbb{Z\times Z}\to W_0\times W_n$ where $W$ is the set of all words that make a grammatical sentence. It is clear that $f$ is one-to-one and onto. We define $f(0,...,n)=(word_0,...,word_n)$ according to the order in which the words appear in a grammatical non-ambiguous sentence. We then define $g:W_0\times\cdots\times W_n\to S$ where $S$ is the set of all grammatical sentences. It's clear that g is one-to-one and onto, $g\circ f:\mathbb{Z^{+}_0\times\cdots Z^{+}_n}\to S$ is also one-to-one and onto.

So is my approach correct??

Comment: How is it clear that the function $f$ you construct (which you don't!) is one-ton-one and onto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an explicit denumeration to show that a set is denumerable. It is enough to show that it is a subset of another denumerable set (in this case, the finite combination of letters, spaces and punctuation).

Comment: But not to forget: show that it is infinite!

Comment: You are right @HagenvonEitzen, thank you.